# Error while running simple flutter application - A GlobalKey was used multiple times inside one widget's child list

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I'm new to flutter and I'm learning it by developing a simple application. Here's the code of my **main.dart** file.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main(){
   runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context){
      return MaterialApp(
         title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
         home: Scaffold(
           appBar: AppBar(
             title: Text("Welcome to flutter"),
           ),
           body: Center(
             child: Text("Hello Wolrd"),
           ),
        ),
     );
  }
}
```

Now I'm facing some issues while running this application. I'm running this application on my phone with help of android studio via USB debugging.
[image]

I couldn't find any solutions on the internet to fix this. Am I missing something or doing some wrong stuff here? Kindly help me out.

Comment: Did you try totally restarting your app?

Answer (score -2):

I also got this problem.Uninstall app and rerun,it worked!